# Android take photo with a custom UI

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, surfaceview, front-camera

In my app I have to take a picture with the FRONT CAMERA, but I do NOT need to use the camera app. I have a custom layout with a button to take the picture. Also I need to save the photo to a Bitmap because I have to send it to my webservice.

An example would be really helpful.

I have gone through the [Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) but I didn't get it too well. I know that I have to use a CameraPreview class and A CameraACtivity but so far I couldn't make it. Need help.

Comment: What does "I couldn't make it" mean? There is a [separate tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html) in the documentation besides the page you wrote. I maintain [a library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) that tries to make it a bit easier to write an app that takes pictures. However, in general, writing a camera app is not easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go dude, this code does exactly what you are looking for:

You can download the whole project from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wta4r39junrcvql/com.test.zip) and play with it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 500;
    private final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    private Context context = MainActivity.this;
    private Camera camera;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private ImageView btn_shutter;
    private LinearLayout btn_layout;
    private TextView btn_retake;
    private TextView btn_keep;
    private boolean previewing = false;
    private ImageView temp_pic;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
        btn_shutter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_shutter);
        btn_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn_layout);
        btn_retake = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_retake);
        btn_keep = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keep);
        temp_pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.temp_pic);

        try
        {
            surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        OnClickListener click = new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                switch(v.getId())
                {
                    case R.id.btn_shutter:
                    {
                        camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

                        onTakePick();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_retake:
                    {
                        camera.startPreview();

                        onRetakePic();

                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.btn_keep:
                    {
                        new TakeScreeShot().execute();

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        btn_shutter.setOnClickListener(click);
        btn_retake.setOnClickListener(click);
        btn_keep.setOnClickListener(click);
    }




    private final String TAG = "horia";
    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte [] data, Camera camera)
        {
            new ProcessRawBitmap(data).execute();
        }
    };



    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromBytes(byte[] imageContent)
    {
        try
        {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageContent, 0, imageContent.length);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }



    private void onRetakePic()
    {
        temp_pic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        surfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final TranslateAnimation anim_hide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, 
                                                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, 
                                                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0, 
                                                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1);
        anim_hide.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        anim_hide.setFillAfter(true);

        anim_hide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                btn_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_layout.setAnimation(null);

                final TranslateAnimation anim_show = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, 
                                                                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, 
                                                                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1,
                                                                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
                anim_show.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
                anim_show.setFillAfter(true);

                anim_show.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
                    {
                        btn_shutter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                    {
                        btn_shutter.setAnimation(null);
                    }
                });

                btn_shutter.startAnimation(anim_show);
            }
        });

        btn_layout.startAnimation(anim_hide);
    }



    private void onTakePick()
    {
        final TranslateAnimation anim_hide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, 
                                                                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, 
                                                                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0, 
                                                                            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1);
        anim_hide.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        anim_hide.setFillAfter(true);

        anim_hide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                btn_shutter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_shutter.setAnimation(null);

                final TranslateAnimation anim_show = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, 
                                                                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, 
                                                                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1, 
                                                                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
                anim_show.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
                anim_show.setFillAfter(true);

                anim_show.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
                    {
                        btn_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                    {
                        btn_layout.setAnimation(null);
                    }
                });

                btn_layout.startAnimation(anim_show);
            }
        });

        btn_shutter.startAnimation(anim_hide);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        try
        {
            try
            {
                if(null != camera)
                {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    camera.release();
                    camera = null;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {
        try
        {
            if (previewing)
            {
                camera.stopPreview();
            }

            if(null != camera)
            {
                Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

                if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
                {
//                  LOG.x("ROTATION_0");
                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                }

                if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
                {
//                  LOG.x("ROTATION_90");
                }

                if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
                {
//                  LOG.x("ROTATION_180");
                }

                if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
                {
//                  LOG.x("ROTATION_270");
                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                }

                previewCamera();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {

    }



    public void previewCamera()
    {        
        try 
        {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);          
            camera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private File getOutputMediaFile(int type)
    {
        if (true == isExternalStoragePresent())
        {
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MyTestPicsFolder");

            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists())
            {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs())
                {
                    Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            File mediaFile;

            if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)
            {
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            }
            else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            {
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

            return mediaFile;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setMessage("No storage space found, can't save the video.").setPositiveButton("Ok", null).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }



    private class TakeScreeShot extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
    {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params)
        {
            try
            {
                View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                File imageFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);      
                if (imageFile == null)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
                    return null;
                }


                OutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fout);
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }



    private Bitmap bitmapRotate(File f)
    {
        try
        {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            int angle = 0;

            if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90)
            {
                angle = 90;
            }
            else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)
            {
                angle = 180;
            }
            else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270)
            {
                angle = 270;
            }

            Matrix mat = new Matrix();
            mat.postRotate(angle);

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }



    private class ProcessRawBitmap extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
    {
        private byte [] data;

        public ProcessRawBitmap(byte [] data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params)
        {
            Bitmap bit = getBitmapFromBytes(data);

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

            if (pictureFile == null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
                return null;
            }

            try
            {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

                bit = bitmapRotate(pictureFile);

                if(null != bit)
                {
                    temp_pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    temp_pic.setImageBitmap(bit);
                    surfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                pictureFile.delete();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    public static boolean isExternalStoragePresent()
    {
        boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
        boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
        {
            // We can read and write the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        }
        else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state))
        {
            // We can only read the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        }
        else
        {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        }
        if (false == ((mExternalStorageAvailable) && (mExternalStorageWriteable)))
        {
            // Toast.makeText(context, "SD card not present",
        }

        return (mExternalStorageAvailable) && (mExternalStorageWriteable);
    }
}
```